# Как верстать сайт, чтобы под все размеры экрана нормально смотрелся?

Tags: вёрстка

Как верстать сайт, чтобы под все размеры экрана нормально смотрелся?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/

Answer (score 1):

**Адаптивно и кроссбраузерно** (2)

Могут помочь такие линки:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/144003/

http://html5boilerplate.com/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/150447/

http://naikom.ru/blog/archives/5566 (Тут подробно)